# Javascript closure not displaying content

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am trying to do this function closure but its displaying in the console as:

```
function NewsAPI() {
    var authorOfArticle = [], descriptionOfArticle = [], publishedAtDate = [], titleOfArticle = [], urlOfArticle = [], urlToImageOfArticle = [];
    var newsConstructor = new XMLH…
```

I looked at my code and switched things around but all of my attempts failed. Now i need some outside help. Here is my code:

```
function NewsAPI() {
  var authorOfArticle = [],
    descriptionOfArticle = [],
    publishedAtDate = [],
    titleOfArticle = [],
    urlOfArticle = [],
    urlToImageOfArticle = [];
  var newsConstructor = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=c99bdac4799a421cbe9fd3589b60397d',
    InnerNewsAPI;
  newsConstructor.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (newsConstructor.readyState === 4 && newsConstructor.status === 200) {
      var response = newsConstructor.responseText,
        parsedNews = JSON.parse(response);
      for (var i = 0; i < parsedNews["articles"].length; i++) {
        authorOfArticle.push(parsedNews["articles"][i].author); // [0] = author
        descriptionOfArticle.push(parsedNews["articles"][i].description); // [1] = description of article
        publishedAtDate.push(parsedNews["articles"][i].publishedAt); // [2] = date published
        titleOfArticle.push(parsedNews["articles"][i].title); // [3] = title
        urlOfArticle.push(parsedNews["articles"][i].url); // [4] link to source
        urlToImageOfArticle.push(parsedNews["articles"][i].urlToImage); // [5] = image url
      }
      console.log(titleOfArticle);

      InnerNewsAPI = function() {
        $("document").ready(function() {
          $("#a1title").text(titleOfArticle[0]).addClass("article articletitles");
          $("#a1author").text("Author: " + authorOfArticle[0]).addClass("articleauthors");
          $("#a1source").attr("href", urlOfArticle[0]).text(urlOfArticle[0]).addClass("articles articlesources");
          $("#a1image").attr("src", urlToImageOfArticle[0]).addClass("article articleimages");
          $("#a1description").text(descriptionOfArticle[0]).addClass("articledescriptions");
          $("#a2title").text(titleOfArticle[1]).addClass("article articletitles");
          $("#a2author").text("Author: " + authorOfArticle[1]).addClass("articleauthors");
          $("#a2source").attr("href", urlOfArticle[1]).text(urlOfArticle[1]).addClass("articles articlesources");
          $("#a2image").attr("src", urlToImageOfArticle[1]).addClass("article articleimages");
          $("#a2description").text(descriptionOfArticle[1]).addClass("articledescriptions");

          return urlOfArticle;
        }); // put code above this line
      }
    };
    return InnerNewsAPI;
  }
  newsConstructor.open("GET", url, true);
  newsConstructor.send(null);
  //return InnerNewsAPI;

  //return innerNewsAPI();
}
console.log(NewsAPI);
```

Comment: To call a function you have to put `()` after it. `console.log(NewsAPI())`

Comment: The function doesn't return anything, so there's no point in calling `console.log()`.

Comment: Just use `NewsAPI()` to run the function.

Comment: There's no point in returning something from the `onreadystatechange` function. If you want to call `InnerNewsAPI`, put `InnerNewsAPI()` in the function.